# how to interprit this please Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.logo.tm.androidriderapp, PID: 5587
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.logo.tm.androidriderapp/com.logo.tm.androidriderapp.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:715)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                  at com.logo.tm.androidriderapp.Home.onCreate(Home.java:31)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

The home activity in question

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //maps
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        //add simple marker
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(37.7750,122.4183))
                    .title("San Francisco"));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(37.7750,-122.4183),12));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you also post some code here?

Comment: just posted the home activy can this help out please